# Getting view snapshot without alpha of view applied

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I'm doing something that requires me to get a full opacity version of a view snapshot even though the view's .alpha property is set to a non-1 value.

I'm getting my snapshot via quick snapshotting in iOS 7:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0f);
[self drawViewHierarchyInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height) afterScreenUpdates:NO];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I'm looking at converting this to bitmap data and modifying all of the alpha values by 1 - view.alpha. I think this would work, but I need to get non-premultiplied bitmap data.

```
CGContextRef context = NULL;
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
uint32_t *bitmapData;

size_t bitsPerPixel = 32;
size_t bitsPerComponent = 8;
size_t bytesPerPixel = bitsPerPixel / bitsPerComponent;

size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(image);
size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(image);

size_t bytesPerRow = width * bytesPerPixel;
size_t bufferLength = bytesPerRow * height;

colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

if(!colorSpace) {
    NSLog(@"Error allocating color space RGB\n");
    return NULL;
}

// Allocate memory for image data
bitmapData = (uint32_t *)malloc(bufferLength);

if(!bitmapData) {
    NSLog(@"Error allocating memory for bitmap\n");
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    return NULL;
}

//Create bitmap context
context = CGBitmapContextCreate(bitmapData,
                                width,
                                height,
                                bitsPerComponent,
                                bytesPerRow,
                                colorSpace,
                                (kCGBitmapAlphaInfoMask & kCGImageAlphaLast)); //RGBA
```

Unless there is a simpler way to go about this, why can't I get kCGImageAlphaLast to work? kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast seems to work, but this will not work.

```
<Error>: CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination: 8 integer bits/component; 32 bits/pixel; 3-component color space; kCGImageAlphaLast; 8192 bytes/row.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just put this view inside a containerView? Alter the container's alpha instead and leave this 'image producing view' with an alpha of 1.0.... Your UI remains intact and you get your image...